# php .htacces rules using site loading slow

Tags: php, http, https, sitemap

I am using `.htaccess` rules to redirect `http` to `https` and `www` to non `www` page. It also routes `sitemap.php` to `sitemap.xml`.

After using all rules, site loading speed is now slow.

Here are my `.htaccess` rules:

```
## Sitemap Config
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap/sitemap.php
RewriteRule ^sitemap-(.*).xml$ sitemap/sitemap.php?id=$1
## WWW to non WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
## HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Not related to PHP in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You should also add `L` flag to first part of code, `L`  flag means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed , so add it if you want to do an internal redirection like this :

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap/sitemap.php [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap-(.*).xml$ sitemap/sitemap.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This part of code :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
## HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

could be combined like this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So , the above code will match against both `http and https` requests with `www` and remove `www` also will match against `http` requests and force them into `https` and passes only `https` requests without `www` and that what you want excately.

**Note:** clear browser cache and test it .

Comment: problem not solved. Video view page loading slow please see this https://yeuteu.com

Comment: @SouravSarkar put https code part at the top of code